# What determines which url will be displayed in the browser when using portlets?

Tags: url, liferay, portlet, portal

What determines which url will be displayed in the browser when using multiple portlets in the same page? Is it the one that loads last? Is there a way to specify which portlet's url I want to display once all portlets have been loaded?

Comment: The URL is attached to the page, not to a portlet.

Answer (score 1):

In Liferay the page URL's are liferay pages (there are page types like portlet, link to page, external url etc.)

If you have a standard page type of portlet, then you can add multiple portlets on the page. This moment, the page will always show the `friendlyURL` which is configured for the page.

Also, you cannot change the friendly URLs dynamically.

So, page is a logical group of the portlets which is identified by unique URL (within the group) to access the same.